# Calculation of $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{a}{k^2} \right)$?

Tags: infinite-product

I am curious how to calculate the infinite product

$$ \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{a}{k^2} \right). $$

WolframAlpha [reports](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%20of%20%281%2Ba%2Fk%5E2%29%20from%20k%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity) that it is equal to approximately

$$ \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{a}{k^2} \right) \approx \frac{0.31831 \sinh (3.14159 \sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}} $$

which I suspect might be given by

$$ \frac{\sinh (\pi \sqrt{a})}{\pi \sqrt{a}}. $$

This in turn suggests that

$$ \sinh a = a \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{\pi^2 k^2} \right), $$

which is confirmed by WolframAlpha.

However, I don't know how this is derived.

Comment: Related: [$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\; \left(1+ \frac{1}{\pi ^2n^2}\right) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359638) (in fact you'll find an answer there)

Comment: see [this](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-97-prev.pdf).

Comment: @Did I think that's a duplicate comment...

Comment: When you study complex analysis, you will learn about the infinite product form for the trig functions.  (And that the hyperbolic functions are really trig functions in disguise.)

Comment: @Zach466920 Did you get interested in what happens when one signals a post as duplicate? You might want to.

Comment: @Did Sorry about that, you must be a moderator or something similar....

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).