# show this inequality to find simple proof $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+\frac{1}{i^2})<4$

Tags: inequality

show this 
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)<4\tag{1}$$

I have know this can find the value
$$\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)=\dfrac{\sinh{\pi}}{\pi}=3.67<4$$[Prove that $\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty} (1+1/k^2) = \sinh(\pi)/(2 \pi)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994156/prove-that-prod-k-2-infty-11-k2-sinh-pi-2-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I think the problem $(1)$ have Simple proof?That is, we avoid calculating the result to give proof with inequality? Thanks

Comment: @RossMillikan,the links is $\prod_{k=2}^{+\infty}$ and my problem is $\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that 
$$\prod^N_{n=2} \left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right) = \prod^N_{n=2} \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n^2} = \frac12\cdot\frac{N+1}{N} > \frac12,$$
and that

$$\prod^N_{n=2}\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)\prod^N_{n=2}\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right) =\prod^N_{n=2}\left(1-\frac1{n^4}\right)< 1.$$
So
$$\prod^N_{n=2}\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right) < 2,$$
and we are done.